# Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I read about Java's type erasure [on Oracle's website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

**When does type erasure occur?** At compile time or runtime? When the class is loaded? When the class is instantiated?

A lot of sites (including the official tutorial mentioned above) say type erasure occurs at compile time. If the type information is completely removed at compile time, how does the JDK check type compatibility when a method using generics is invoked with no type information or wrong type information?

Consider the following example: Say class `A` has a method, `empty(Box<? extends Number> b)`. We compile `A.java` and get the class file `A.class`.

```
public class A {
    public static void empty(Box<? extends Number> b) {}
}
```

```
public class Box<T> {}
```

Now we create another class `B` which invokes the method `empty` with a non-parameterized argument (raw type): `empty(new Box())`. If we compile `B.java` with `A.class` in the classpath, javac is smart enough to raise a warning. So `A.class` *has* some type information stored in it.

```
public class B {
    public static void invoke() {
        // java: unchecked method invocation:
        //  method empty in class A is applied to given types
        //  required: Box<? extends java.lang.Number>
        //  found:    Box
        // java: unchecked conversion
        //  required: Box<? extends java.lang.Number>
        //  found:    Box
        A.empty(new Box());
    }
}
```

My guess would be that type erasure occurs when the class is loaded, but it is just a guess. So when does it happen?

Comment: A more "generic" version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Comment: @afryingpan: The article mentioned in my answer explains in detail how and when type erasure happens. It also explains when type information is kept. In other words: reified generics is available in Java, contrary to widespread belief. See: https://rgomes.info/using-typetokens-to-retrieve-generic-parameters/

Answer (score 282):

Type erasure applies to the *use* of generics. There's definitely metadata in the class file to say whether or not a method/type *is* generic, and what the constraints are etc. But when generics are *used*, they're converted into compile-time checks and execution-time casts. So this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Hi");
String x = list.get(0);
```

is compiled into

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hi");
String x = (String) list.get(0);
```

At execution time there's no way of finding out that `T=String` for the list object - that information is gone.

... but the `List<T>` interface itself still advertises itself as being generic.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the compiler does retain the information about the *variable* being a `List<String>` - but you still can't find out that `T=String` for the list object itself.

Comment: No, even in the use of a generic type there may be metadata available at runtime. A local variable is not accessible through Reflection, but for a method parameter declared as "List<String> l",  there will be type metadata at runtime, available through the Reflection API. Yep, "type erasure" is not as simple as many people think...

Comment: @Rogerio: As I replied to your comment, I believe you're getting confused between being able to get the type of a *variable* and being able to get the type of an *object*. The object itself doesn't know its type argument, even though the field does.

Comment: Of course, just looking at the object itself you can't know that it's a List<String>. But objects don't just appear from nowhere. They are created locally, passed in as a method invocation argument,  returned as the return value from a method call, or read from a field of some object... In all these cases you CAN know at runtime what the generic type is, either implicitly or by using the Java Reflection API.

Comment: @Rogerio: How do you know where the object has come from though? If you have a parameter of type `List<? extends InputStream>` how can you know what type it was when it was created? Even if you *can* find out the type of the field the reference has been stored in, why should you have to? Why should you be able to get all the rest of the information about the object at execution time, but not its generic type arguments? You seem to be trying to make type erasure out to be this tiny thing which doesn't affect developers really - whereas I find it to be a very *significant* problem in some cases.

Comment: But type erasure IS a tiny thing which doesn't really affect developers! Of course, I can't speak for others, but in MY experience it never was a big deal. I actually take advantage of runtime type information in the design of my Java mocking API (JMockit); ironically, .NET mocking APIs seem to take less advantage of the generic type system available in C#.

Answer (score 112):

The compiler is responsible for understanding Generics at compile time. The compiler is also responsible for throwing away this "understanding" of generic classes, in a process we call *type erasure*. All happens at compile time.

**Note:** Contrary to beliefs of majority of Java developers, it is possible to keep compile-time type information and retrieve this information at runtime, despite in a very restricted way. In other words: **Java does provide reified generics in a very restricted way**.

### Regarding type erasure

Notice that, at compile-time, the compiler has full type information available but this information is intentionally dropped *in general* when the byte code is generated, in a process known as *type erasure*. This is done this way due to compatibility issues: The intention of language designers was providing full source code compatibility and full byte code compatibility between versions of the platform. If it were implemented differently, you would have to recompile your legacy applications when migrating to newer versions of the platform. The way it was done, all method signatures are preserved (source code compatibility) and you don't need to recompile anything (binary compatibility).

### Regarding reified generics in Java

If you need to keep compile-time type information, you need to employ anonymous classes.
The point is: in the very special case of anonymous classes, it is possible to retrieve full compile-time type information at runtime which, in other words means: reified generics. This means that the compiler does not throw away type information when anonymous classes are involved; this information is kept in the generated binary code and the runtime system allows you to retrieve this information.

I've written an article about this subject:

https://rgomes.info/using-typetokens-to-retrieve-generic-parameters/

A note about the technique described in the article above is that the technique is obscure for majority of developers. Despite it works and works well, most developers feel confused or uncomfortable with the technique. If you have a shared code base or plan to release your code to the public, I do not recommend the above technique. On the other hand, if you are the sole user of your code, you can take advantage of the power this technique delivers to you.

### Sample code

The article above has links to sample code.

Comment: @will824: I've massively improved the answer and I've added a link to some test cases. Cheers :)

Comment: Actually, they didn't maintain both binary and source compatibility: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html
Where can I read more about their intention? Docs say that it uses type erasure, but doesn't say why.

Comment: @Richard Indeed, excellent article! You could add that local classes work too and that, in both cases (anonymous and local classes), information about the desired type argument is kept only in case of direct access `new Box<String>() {};` not in case of indirect access `void foo(T) {...new Box<T>() {};...}` because the compiler does not keep type information for the enclosing method declaration.

Comment: I've fixed a broken link to my article. I'm slowly de-googling my life and reclaiming my data. :-)

Answer (score 37):

If you have a field that is a generic type, its type parameters are compiled into the class.

If you have a method that takes or returns a generic type, those type parameters are compiled into the class.

This information is what the compiler uses to tell you that you can't pass a `Box<String>` to the `empty(Box<T extends Number>)` method.

The API is complicated, but you can inspect this type information through the reflection API with methods like [`getGenericParameterTypes`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes()), [`getGenericReturnType`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType()), and, for fields, [`getGenericType`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()).

If you have code that uses a generic type, the compiler inserts casts as needed (in the caller) to check types. The generic objects themselves are just the raw type; the parameterized type is "erased". So, when you create a `new Box<Integer>()`, there is no information about the `Integer` class in the `Box` object.

[Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001) is the best reference I've seen for Java Generics.

Comment: Actually, it is the _formal_ generic type of the fields and methods that are compiled into the class, i.e., typicall "T". To obtain the _real_ type of the generic type, you must use the ["anonymous-class trick"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection/15999255#15999255).

Answer (score 14):

[Generics in Java Language](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf) is a really good guide on this topic.

> Generics are implemented by Java
>   compiler as a front-end conversion
>   called erasure. You can (almost) think
>   of it as a source-to-source
>   translation, whereby the generic
>   version of `loophole()` is converted to
>   the non-generic version.

So, it's at compile time. The JVM will never know which `ArrayList` you used.

I'd also recommend Mr. Skeet's answer on [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)

Answer (score 11):

The term "type erasure" is not really the correct description of Java's problem with generics.
Type erasure is not per se a bad thing, indeed it is very necessary  for performance and is often used in several languages like C++, Haskell, D.

Before you disgust, please recall the correct definition of type erasure from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)

**What is type erasure?**

> type erasure refers to the load-time process by which explicit type annotations are removed from a program, before it is executed at run-time

Type erasure means to throw away type tags created at design time or inferred type tags at compile time such that the compiled program in binary code does not contain any type tags.
And this is the case for every programming language compiling to binary code except in some cases where you need runtime tags. These exceptions include for instance all existential types (Java Reference Types which are subtypeable, Any Type in many languages, Union Types).
The reason for type erasure is that programs get transformed to a language which is in some kind uni-typed (binary language only allowing bits) as types are abstractions only and assert a structure for its values and the appropriate semantics to handle them.

So this is in return, a normal natural thing.

Java's problem is different and caused to how it reifies.

The often made statements about Java does not have reified generics is also wrong.

Java does reify, but in a wrong way due to backward compatibility.

**What is reification?**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science))

> Reification is the process by which an abstract idea about a computer program is turned into an explicit data model or other object created in a programming language.

Reification means to convert something abstract (Parametric Type) into something concrete (Concrete Type) by specialization.

We illustrate this by a simple example:

An ArrayList with definition:

```
ArrayList<T>
{
    T[] elems;
    ...//methods
}
```

is an abstraction, in detail a type constructor, which gets "reified" when specialized with a concrete type, say Integer:

```
ArrayList<Integer>
{
    Integer[] elems;
}
```

where `ArrayList<Integer>` is really a type.

But this is **exactly** the thing what Java **does not!!!**, instead they reify constantly abstract types with their bounds, i.e. producing the same concrete type independent of the parameters passed in for specialization:

```
ArrayList
{
    Object[] elems;
}
```

which is here reified with the implicit bound Object (`ArrayList<T extends Object>` == `ArrayList<T>`).

Despite that it makes generic arrays unusable and cause some strange errors for raw types:

```
List<String> l= List.<String>of("h","s");
List lRaw=l
l.add(new Object())
String s=l.get(2) //Cast Exception
```

it causes a lot of ambiguities as

```
void function(ArrayList<Integer> list){}
void function(ArrayList<Float> list){}
void function(ArrayList<String> list){}
```

refer to the same function:

```
void function(ArrayList list)
```

and therefore generic method overloading can't be used in Java.

Answer (score 10):

Type erasure occurs at compile time. What type erasure means is that it will forget about the generic type, not about every type. Besides, there will still be metadata about the types being generic. For example

```
Box<String> b = new Box<String>();
String x = b.getDefault();
```

is converted to

```
Box b = new Box();
String x = (String) b.getDefault();
```

at compile time. You may get warnings not because the compiler knows about what type is the generic of, but on the contrary, because it doesn't know enough so it cannot guarantee type safety.

Additionally, the compiler does retain the type information about the parameters on a method call, which you can retrieve via reflection.

This [guide](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001) is the best I've found on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered with type erasure in Android. In production we use gradle with minify option. After minification I've got fatal exception. I've made simple function to show inheritance chain of my object:

```
public static void printSuperclasses(Class clazz) {
    Type superClass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();

    Log.d("Reflection", "this class: " + (clazz == null ? "null" : clazz.getName()));
    Log.d("Reflection", "superClass: " + (superClass == null ? "null" : superClass.toString()));

    while (superClass != null && clazz != null) {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        superClass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();

        Log.d("Reflection", "this class: " + (clazz == null ? "null" : clazz.getName()));
        Log.d("Reflection", "superClass: " + (superClass == null ? "null" : superClass.toString()));
    }
}
```

And there is two results of this function:

Not minified code:

```
D/Reflection: this class: com.example.App.UsersList
D/Reflection: superClass: com.example.App.SortedListWrapper<com.example.App.Models.User>

D/Reflection: this class: com.example.App.SortedListWrapper
D/Reflection: superClass: android.support.v7.util.SortedList$Callback<T>

D/Reflection: this class: android.support.v7.util.SortedList$Callback
D/Reflection: superClass: class java.lang.Object

D/Reflection: this class: java.lang.Object
D/Reflection: superClass: null
```

Minified code:

```
D/Reflection: this class: com.example.App.UsersList
D/Reflection: superClass: class com.example.App.SortedListWrapper

D/Reflection: this class: com.example.App.SortedListWrapper
D/Reflection: superClass: class android.support.v7.g.e

D/Reflection: this class: android.support.v7.g.e
D/Reflection: superClass: class java.lang.Object

D/Reflection: this class: java.lang.Object
D/Reflection: superClass: null
```

So, in minified code actual parametrized classes are replaced with raw classes types without any type information. 
As a solution for my project i removed all reflection calls and replced them with explicit params types passed in function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check with `javap` that fields, method argument and return value generic arguments are preserved in class files:

```
$ cat Test.java
class Test {
    Class<String> cs;
    Class<Object> co;
    Class c;

    Class<String> ms(Class<String> as) { return null; }
    Class<Object> mo(Class<Object> ao) { return null; }
    Class m(Class a) { return null; }
}
```

```
$ javac ./Test.java
$ javap ./Test.java
Compiled from "Test.java"
class Test {
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.String> ls;
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.Number> li;
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object> lo;
  java.lang.Class l;
  com.kpoc.assistant.Sign();
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.String> ms(java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>);
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.Number> mi(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Number>);
  java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object> mo(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>);
  java.lang.Class m(java.lang.Class);
}
```

So technically there is no reason why JVM can't use this information at runtime. The reasoning why it's not used by JVM is well described in an [article](https://cr.openjdk.org/%7Ebriangoetz/valhalla/erasure.html) by Brian Goetz. There is also a case when it's available at runtime: it's possible to obtain type parameter values for non-generic classes derived from generic ones.

On the other hand the Java compiler is aware about type erasure. It could in some cases adopt translated code for type erasure execution. One example of this is bridge methods. From that point of view type erasure occurs at compile time.