# Is it possible to create a mock object that implements multiple interfaces with EasyMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, easymock

Is it possible to create a mock object that implements several interfaces with EasyMock?

For example, interface `Foo` and interface `Closeable`?

In Rhino Mocks you can provide multiple interfaces when creating a mock object, but EasyMock's `createMock()` method only takes one type.

Is it possbile to achieve this with EasyMock, without resorting to the fallback of creating a temporary interface that extends both `Foo` and `Closeable`, and then mocking that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EasyMock doesn't support this so you're stuck with fallback of the temporary interface.

As an aside, I smell a little bit of a code wiff - should a method really be treating an object as 2 different things, the `Foo` and `Closeable` interface in this case?

This implies to me that the method is performing multiple operations and while I suspect one of those operations is to 'close' the `Closeable`, wouldn't it make more sense for the calling code to decide whether or not the 'close' is required?

Structuring the code this way keeps the 'open' and 'close' in the same `try ... finally` block and IMHO makes the code more readable not to mention the method more general and allows you to pass objects that only implement `Foo`.

Comment: I agree with this, but to expand: if you are using dependency injection, and your class needs both a Foo and a Closable, you should really have two separate setters for those. If you choose to inject the same object for both of these, then great, but I think the class-under-test doesn't need to know that they are the same object - it should treat the Foo as a Foo and the Closeable as a Closeable

Comment: Nick, Matt, thanks for your input. Just to clarify the scenario, the context is that Foo is an interface for a modular add-in system. Third-party modules implement Foo and are then instantiated and used by the framework. They can also optionally implement Closeable, in which case the framework will close them when it has finished using them. Hence, the unit tests need to cover two distinct scenarios: A Foo which is also Closeable, and a Foo which is not Closeable. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @NickHolt: I wouldn't fully agree with you. Consider the case when you have an interface `Person` which has only getters (`getFirstName()`, `getAddress()`, ...) and interface `ModifiablePerson`, that has only setters (`setFirstName()`, `setAddress()`, ...). And now you want to test a SUT, which takes `Person`, but checks if passed object `instanceof ModifiablePerson` and does something based on that. `Closeable` is also a good example: if the object provides an "extended" functionality, which is explicitly checked by `instanceof` and taken advantage of, what is bad in that?

Answer (score 92):

Although I fundamentally agree with Nick Holt's answer, I thought I should point out that [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito) allows to do what you ask with the following call :

```
Foo mock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class, withSettings().extraInterfaces(Bar.class));
```

Obviously you'll have to use the cast: `(Bar)mock` when you need to use the mock as a `Bar` but that cast will not throw `ClassCastException`

Here is an example that is a bit more complete, albeit totally absurd:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

import java.util.Iterator;


public class NonsensicalTest {


    @Test
    public void testRunnableIterator() {
        // This test passes.

        final Runnable runnable = 
                    mock(Runnable.class, withSettings().extraInterfaces(Iterator.class));
        final Iterator iterator = (Iterator) runnable;
        when(iterator.next()).thenReturn("a", 2);
        doThrow(new IllegalStateException()).when(runnable).run();

        assertThat(iterator.next(), is(Matchers.<Object>equalTo("a")));

        try {
            runnable.run();
            fail();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

have you considered something like:

```
interface Bar extends Foo, Closeable {
}
```

and then mock interface Bar?

Comment: Yes, I was just seeing if I could avoid that. Per my question: "Is it possbile to achieve this with EasyMock, without resorting to the fallback of creating a temporary interface that extends both Foo and Closeable, and then mocking that?"

Comment: I like this solution - to create such interface in test class is ok for me, good idea ;-)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative of the [most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270723/1997376) still based on **Mockito** but with annotations. You can set the [`extraInterfaces`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.0/org/mockito/Mock.html#extraInterfaces--) directly from the `Mock` annotation as next:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Mock(extraInterfaces = Closeable.class)
    private Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

**NB:** `extraInterfaces` is of type `Class<?>[]` so you can specify several interfaces if needed.

If you need to mock method calls of the extra interfaces you will need to cast your mock. For example let's say that I want to throw an `IOException` when I call `close()` on my mock `foo`, the corresponding code would then be:

```
Mockito.doThrow(IOException.class).when((Closeable) foo).close();
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting casting exception, what i am missing.
I am running my test case with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR I've just tested with powermockito 2.0.2, and it worked on my side

Comment: i am using 1.5.5 powermock version

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the only mocking tool for Java that has explicit support for mocking multiple interfaces is [JMockit](https://jmockit.dev.java.net). (My inspiration for adding this feature came from Moq and Rhino Mocks, which are .NET tools.)

An example (from the `mockit.ExpectationsUsingMockedTest` JUnit 4 test class):

```
@Test
public <M extends Dependency & Runnable> void mockParameterWithTwoInterfaces(final M mock)
{
   new Expectations()
   {
      {
         mock.doSomething(true); returns("");
         mock.run();
      }
   };

   assertEquals("", mock.doSomething(true));
   mock.run();
}
```

`Dependency` and `Runnable` are interfaces. The `doSomething` method belongs to the first, and `run` to the second.

Comment: This snippet does not seem to create the mock object. How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is to use a [CGLib mixin](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Mixin.html):

```
final Interface1 interface1 = mockery.mock(Interface1.class);
final Interface2 interface2 = mockery.mock(Interface2.class);

service.setDependence(Mixin.create(new Object[]{ interface1, interface2 }));

mockery.checking(new Expectations(){{
    oneOf(interface1).doSomething();
    oneOf(interface2).doNothing();
}});

service.execute();
```

Whether or not this is a good idea, it's something up to discussion...