# How to resolve ClassCastException using Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a `JUnit` test case for a method in which I am getting a `ClassCastException`. I am getting this exception when the request object sets the entity. `serviceRequest.setEntity((ResendDocumentsRequest)request);`

Method under test

```
public Object invokeService(String key, Object request) {
   if( UiIntegrationKeyConstants.RESEND_DOCUMENTS.equals( key ) ) {
        ResendDocumentsServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;

        try {
            ESignatureClient client = (ESignatureClient) AppContext.getBean("eSignatureRestClient");
            ResendDocumentsServiceRequest serviceRequest = client.getResendDocumentsServiceRequest();
            serviceRequest.setEntity((ResendDocumentsRequest)request);

            serviceResponse = client.resendDocuments(serviceRequest);

        } catch (ESignatureClientException e) {
            log.error("Exception while retrieving documents Detail "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return serviceResponse.getEntity();
    }
}
```

JUnit test case

```
private ResendDocumentsServiceRequest resendDocumentsServiceRequest;
private ResendDocumentsServiceResponse resendDocumentsServiceResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Before
public void setUP() {
    mockStatic( AppContext.class );
    esignatureClient = mock( ESignatureClient.class );
    resendDocumentsServiceRequest = mock( ResendDocumentsServiceRequest.class );
    resendDocumentsServiceResponse = mock( ResendDocumentsServiceResponse.class );
}

@Test
public void testESignatureClientException() {
    ESignatureServiceInvoker invoker = new ESignatureServiceInvoker();

    PowerMockito.when( AppContext.getBean( eq( "eSignatureRestClient" ) ) ).thenReturn( esignatureClient );
    when( esignatureClient.getResendDocumentsServiceRequest() ).thenReturn( resendDocumentsServiceRequest );
    try {
        doThrow( new ESignatureClientException() ).when( esignatureClient ).resendDocuments( resendDocumentsServiceRequest );
        resendDocumentsServiceResponse = ( ResendDocumentsServiceResponse ) invoker.invokeService( UiIntegrationKeyConstants.RESEND_DOCUMENTS , resendDocumentsServiceRequest );
    } catch ( ESignatureClientException ex ) {
        assertNotNull( ex );
    }
}
```

stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.whatever.ResendDocumentsServiceRequest$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$15a76565 cannot be cast to com.whatever.ResendDocumentsRequest
```

Comment: You can tell mockito to mock additional interfaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170708/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mock-object-that-implements-multiple-interfaces-with

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. Is there anything I could add to the answer to also make it upvote-worthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mocked your object to be a **ResendDocumentsServiceRequest**.

The production code expects an instance of **ResendDocumentsRequest**.

In other words: expected is A, provided is B. That would only work if `B extends A`, or `B implements A`. In that sense: this has nothing to do with mocking per se. But with the fact that you somehow provide an B object to your production code ... that should be of type A instead. When you do that at "real production runtime", too - you will run into the same error.

But we can't tell you A) why you did this nor B) what the correct solution is. As you stated that these are two disjunct classes - you have to figure if this fail is actually exposing a bug in your production code (by assuming that objects could be cast this way) - or in your test setup.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
The `resendDocumentsServiceRequest` object in your junit must extend or implement the `ResendDocumentsRequest` class or interface.

More Details:

1. Create a static class (in the junit test class) that both extends the `ResendDocumentsServiceRequest` class and implements the `ResendDocumentsRequest` interface.  I'll call this the `TestKapow` class.
2. Change the type of the `resendDocumentsServiceRequest` object to `TestKapow`.
3. Joy.

Comment: I am not really certain about your solution. ResendDocumentsRequest is not an interface and I can't extend two classes.

Comment: If that is the case, the the code (which is currently compiling) will not compile.  Is ResendDocumentsServiceRequest an interface?  If not, refer to the first sentence of this comment.