# Not implementing generic method in generics class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Imagine code like this:

```
public class Value<T> {
    private T value;

    public Value(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int size() {
        return sizeOf(value);
    }

    private int sizeOf(int value) {
        return Integer.BYTES;
    }

    private int sizeOf(String value) {
        return value.length() * Character.BYTES;
    }
}
```

and somewhere (e.g. `main`)

```
Value<String> value = new Value<String>("hello");
```

The problem is that the code will not compile, because I haven't implemented `sizeOf(T value)`, **but I don't understand why would the compiler complain --- it sees that I only use it with `<T=String>`**. And if I implement the generic `sizeOf(T value)` , it will take precedence (as explained here [Java generics (template) specialization possible (overriding template types with specific types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988180/java-generics-template-specialization-possible-overriding-template-types-with) )

Note that the solution proposed there (having a `StringValue` subclass) doesn't really apply in my case, because I already have some subclasses which I am using, so I would need to create lots of extra classes (times by types)

[image]

But I would prefer something much more straight-forward, such as this

[image]

Comment: "but I don't understand why would the compiler complain --- it sees that I only use it with `<T=String>`" - This is not how generics work in Java. They are quite different from C++'s template variables. You need a methode `sizeOf` that satisfies the errasure given by `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `sizeOf(T value)` because `T` can be of any type, so to maintain type controll, compiler needs "universal" version of `sizeOf` method that will hindle any possible type.

Think of what would happend if you would use something like `new Value<List<Object>>(new ArrayList<Object>).size()` - what would happen then as you have no method specialized in returning size of collection?

The thing is, that during runtime, **generic type is erased**, so JVM have no idea whitch of the overloaded methods should be used. Check more info about type erasure here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no getting around having to provide an implementation for `size()`. Your code is half way to the double dispatch pattern, but going all the way isn't possible, because you've got no way of requiring types like String to implement `size()`.

One approach is to require the size code on construction:

```
public class Value<T> {
    private T value;
    private Function<T, Integer> size;

    public Value(T value, Function<T, Integer> size) {
        this.value = value;
        this.size;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size.apply(value);
    }
}
```

To create a `Value<String>` for example:

```
 Value<String> val = new Value("foo", s -> s.length() * Character.BYTES)
```

or if that doesn't work, use `instanceof` for supported types:

```
public int size() {
    if (value instanceof Integer)
        return Integer.BYTES;
    if (value instanceof String)
        return ((String)value).length() * Character.BYTES;
    // other supported types
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```