# Unable to specialize method templatization using the subclassing approach

Tags: java, generics

```
public class CSVParser {  
  protected <T extends Message> void addMessageToResult(Message message, Descriptor descriptor, ImmutableList.Builder<T> messageListBuilder) {
    . . . 
  }
```

For DynamicMessage I wanted to have a different handling so I tried

```
public class CSVParserDynamicMessage extends CSVParser {
  protected<DynamicMessage> void addMessageToResult(Message message, Descriptor descriptor, ImmutableList.Builder<DynamicMessage> messageListBuilder) {
    messageListBuilder.add(DynamicMessage.parseFrom(descriptor, message.toByteString()));
}
```

But it gives the compilation error

> 'addMessageToResult(Message, Descriptor, Builder)' in 'com.google.cloud.verticals.telco.taap.dataflow.dataingestion.common.parsers.CSVParserDynamicMessage' clashes with 'addMessageToResult(Message, Descriptor, Builder)' in 'com.google.cloud.verticals.telco.taap.dataflow.dataingestion.common.parsers.CSVParser'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I'm having to do the ugly method below (haven't yet attempted to run and see if it actually works):

```
@Override
  protected<T extends Message> void addMessageToResult(Message message, Descriptor descriptor, ImmutableList.Builder<T> messageListBuilder)
    throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    messageListBuilder.add((T) DynamicMessage.parseFrom(descriptor, message.toByteString()));
}
```

Note that my attempt of subclassing was inspired from [Java generics (template) specialization possible (overriding template types with specific types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988180/java-generics-template-specialization-possible-overriding-template-types-with) but the difference seems to be that in my case the template paramter T doesn't exist at class level but only at method level. I'm not able to understand why it doesn't work for my usecase.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

#### What means T

Generic type parameters like `T`, `U`, `R` - are simply placeholders for types, but not the actual types. By convention type parameters are denoted with a single letter but multi-character type parameter will also compile:

```
public <Something> void doIt(Something s) {}
```

`Something` will not be treated by the compiler as a class or interface name, it's just a placeholder.

```
protected <DynamicMessage> void addMessageToResult(Message message, Descriptor descriptor, ImmutableList.Builder<DynamicMessage> messageListBuilder) {}
```

As well as `DynamicMessage` is a placeholder like `T`. That means that you've changed the generic type parameter declared by in the super class as `T extends Message` to an arbitrary `T`. Which is incorrect.

At the beginning I didn't spotted your intention to override a generic method with a non-generic one, that would not work.

The reason for that is that `T extends Message` compiles to `Object` due to generic type erasure. I.e. you might think of it, as there's a non-generic method with an argument of `Object` type declared in the parent class, and therefore it's not possible to override it by providing `DynamicMessage` as type instead of `Object`.

A generic method can be overridden only by another generic method, which generic type parameters are precisely the same.

---

The problem is fully described in the error message: you can't have two method with the same name and arguments that differ only by a generic type parameter, due to generic type erasure.

For instance, these two methods will clash (i.e. their signatures will be treated as they are the same):

```
public void doIt(List<Integer> list) {}
public void doIt(List<String> list) {}
```

Because at runtime, there would be only a `List<Object>` and safe *checkcasts* added by the compiler.

***The remedy when we need two distinct methods:***

- the method signatures should differ either by method-name, or by the set of parameters (*generic type parameters would not be taken into account*).

Comment: But my intention is for the method signatures to be treated the same, because I'm trying to override in my subclass. What is the problem here?

Comment: @HughDarling I didn't notice your initial intention to override the generic method. Basically, `<DynamicMessage>` in your code is an equivalent of `T` it's not the actual type, that's not what expected to get. And there's no way to change the generic parameter declared by the method in the parent class. Updated the answer.