# What is erasure – what 4 restrictions does erasure place on generics?

Tags: java, erasure-code

Java - 
What is erasure – what 4 restrictions does erasure place on generics?

Comment: or frantically stalling for time in a phone interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe looking at [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java) Will help.