# Check the class name of the reference holding an object in Java

Tags: java

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class TestType {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      A a = new B();
      // I wish to use reference 'a' to check the Reference-Type which is 'A'.
   }
}
```

Is is possible? If no, then please specif the reason.

Comment: You can't. The static type of local variables is not retained in the bytecode, nor at runtime. (If it's a field, you can use reflection on the field's containing class to get the field's type.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `a.getClass()` then it will always return you instance of class from which this object was created. In your case it is `B` so it will return you `B.class`.

Now if you want to call method on `a` and get class as `A.class` then you will not able to do it normal way.

One way out would be define method in `A`

```
public static Class<A> getType() {
        return A.class;
    }
```

and then you can call `a.getType()` which is `A.class` . We are making use of static method here because they are not overridden.

Comment: But this method would need added to every class for consistency , so when getType is called the method would be called for class `B`.

Comment: Updated the answer to make use of static methods.

Comment: Yes the solution worked. :) It was very elegant and simple solution.

Comment: Static methods are not overridden and hence there is no issue in using the method.

Answer (score 3):

[Chris Jester-Young's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703285/check-the-class-name-of-the-reference-holding-an-object-in-java#comment17150810_12703285) was excellent. It says:

> You can't. The static type of local variables is not retained in the bytecode, nor at runtime. (If it's a field, you can use reflection on the field's containing class to get the field's type.)

See also [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)

And http://gafter.blogspot.com/search?q=super+type+token.

Answer (score 2):

> Check the class name of the reference holding an object in Java

You can't.

1. There is no such thing as '*the* reference holding an object. There could be zero such references, or there could be sixten gazillion of them.
2. You can't get it/them from inside the object being held.