# Java typechecking error in long "extends" chain

Tags: java, typechecking

I am a bit baffled about Java type checking:

I have a static method declared as:

```
public static void register(EClass eClass, Class<? extends Page<EObject>> pClass) { ... }
```

I call it as:

```
Page.register(HyconmdePackage.Literals.STATION, StationPage.class);
```

where the second argument is declared as (forget about the first one: it's ok):

```
public class StationPage extends Page<Station> { ...
public abstract class Page<O> { ...
public interface Station extends Identifiable { ...
public interface Identifiable extends EObject { ...
```

but I get the error:

```
The method register(EClass, Class<? extends Page<EObject>>) in the type Page is not applicable for the arguments (EClass, Class<StationPage>)
```

I tried also declaring Page as:

```
public abstract class Page<O extends EObject> { ...
```

but the error remains and I have further problems in class Page.

What's my error? (I hope this is enough to guess the problem; trimming down program to size to have a working example would not be a trivial task)

TiA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StationPage` extends `Page<Station>`, but your method signature requires it to extend `Page<EObject>`.

Note that, even though `Station` (indirectly) extends `EObject`, this does not mean that `Page<Station>` extends `Page<EObject>`. So you cannot use `Page<Station>` when a `Page<EObject>` is expected.

Declare the method like this:

```
public static void register(EClass eClass,
    Class<? extends Page<? extends EObject>> pClass)
```

You can ofcourse also use type parameters instead of wildcards:

```
public static <P extends Page<E>, E extends EObject> register(EClass eClass,
    Class<P> pClass)
```

Comment: Weird: if I put **both** methods I get error `Erasure of method register(EClass, Class<? extends Page<EObject>>) is the same as another method in type Page<O>`. I assume it means Compiler **knows** the methods are different, but it also knows JVM won't be able to distinguish. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, because of [type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Simple. `Page<Station>` is not considered to extend `Page<EObject>`. Check again the generics tutorial at oracle.com

To see what I mean, look how would this code work if `Page<Station>` was considered to extend `Page<EObject>`

```
public void addItem(Page<EObject> page, EObject item) {
  page.add(item);
  ...
}

addItem(new StationPage(), new EObject());
```

That would result in an error, since you are attempting to pass an `EObject` to a method that expects `Station`. An error that the JVM would not be able to identify as such, since the generics information is not used at runtime. So, the compiler *must* interpret that as a compilation error, and `StationPage` does not extend from `Page<Object>`

Using generics as Jesper instructed

```
public void addItem(Page<? extends EObject> page, EObject item) {
```

will allow the compilation, but will put restrictions in the type of operations that you may use with the `page` parameter (it will not allow to call `page.addItem`, exactly for the same motive).