# Using wildcard in method argument

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I have declared a method whose argument is subtype of `Number` as given below:

```
public static void organizeData(java.util.List<? extends Number> c) {
    //operation on the list
}
```

I am able to pass any non-parameterized lists as argument. So what is the point of using wildcard `<? extends Number>`?

```
List newList = new LinkedList<>();
ClassName.organizeData(newList);
```

Why do I get element of type `Object` from `c`? And not of type `Number`? Is there a way to allow only subtypes of a type to be passed as arguments as opposed to allowing non-parameterized arguments also?

Comment: You cannot prevent that. A user can always cast first to the rawtype and then to whatever is required. Generics have their limitations and rawtypes always break them.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking three questions here, I will answer them separately. By the way, you would find it valuable to read the [Java Generics FAQ - considered by many to be the canonical reference on the subject](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html):

1. **So what is the point of using wildcard `<? extends Number>`?**

You need to use the wildcard for the times when the parameterized argument is a subclass of `Number`, say, `Integer`. For instance:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        organizeData(newList); // This works!
        anotherMethod(newList); // Doesn't compile
    }

    private static void organizeData(List<? extends Number> list) {

    }

    private static void anotherMethod(List<Number> list) {

    }
}
```

The second method call fails with the compilation error:

```
NumberTest.java:9: error: method anotherMethod in class NumberTest cannot be applied to given types;
                        anotherMethod(newList); // Doesn't compile
                        ^
  required: List<Number>
  found: List<Integer>
  reason: actual argument List<Integer> cannot be converted to List<Number> by method invocation conversion
1 error
```

---

2. **Why do I get element of type `Object` from `c`? And not of type `Number`?**

The reason you get a type of `Object` in your second case is because [you are using the Raw Type.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) You should never use a raw type if you can avoid it for that reason - you lose all the advantages of compiler type checking.

---

3. **Is there a way to allow only subtypes of a type to be passed as arguments as opposed to allowing non-parameterized arguments also?**

You cannot prevent [Heap Pollution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution) in the way you describe because someone can always cast to the Raw type and then to whatever is required. Generics are a compile time only construct, and [are ultimately erased after compilation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java) This is why the **Unchecked Type Conversion** warning can only be suppressed via annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that in Java generics are a compile-time construct to help with type-safety. At run-time, type erasure converts all generic types to `Object` and add casting where required. If you bypass the compile-time checking by using raw types (for which the compiler gives you a warning) you have bypassed the benefit of generics (compile-time type checking and run-time safe casting).

Answer (score 0):

Generics in Java are implemented via Type erasure. i.e: type information that you specify in <> do not exist during runtime. During compile time the java compiler makes use of the information given in <> to make sure that everything is in order. If however you do not specify the type in <> as you have done for the variable 'newList' nothing prevents you from passing it to the 'organizeData' method.