# Java: extend from a generic class with a specified type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to extend a generic class, like:

```
public class GenericClass<T> implements GenericClassInterface<T>
{
     public T myMethod(String typeID) {
        T test = _get_test_value_; // here I use jackson to retrieve T de-serialized from JSON
        return T;
     }
}
```

Then I extend that class:

```
public class SpecificClass extends GenericClass<CustomType> implements SpecificClassInterface
{
     public CustomType getIstance(String typeID) {
          return super.myMethod(typeID);
     }
}
```

The code compiles correctly, but when I debug I find out that type `T`, when myMethod is called from SpecificClass, is `Object`, and not `CustomType`, even if I specified `CustomType` when I extended `GenericClass` in `SpecificClass`.

How come? Is this a limitation of generics in Java?

Answer (score 3):

The type parameter `T` is not available in runtime (during debugging). This is indeed a limitation of generics in Java and referred to as type erasure. (All type parameters are transformed to `Object` as you have observed.)

See for instance

- [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), or
- [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)

Comment: Then what is the reason to have extended the GenericClass passing a type to T, as in "extends GenericClass<CustomType>"? It's totally useless? And, if so, how can I implement/simulate a real generic in Java?

Comment: The T is around just for type checking purposes. I'm not sure why you say it's useless. A common trick is to pass the Class-object to the constructor. See for instance the constructor of [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#EnumMap%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: @CarmineGiangregorio, did you understand my answer? Or do you want me to elaborate on something?