# getDeclaredMethods on given class that implements interface give more results why?

Tags: spring, reflection, groovy

I have this Groovy snippet in my Spring application

```
 Class.forName(com.example.Name).getDeclaredMethods().each { method ->
                if (method.getName() == ('findId')) {
                    println method.returnType.name
                    println method.getName()
                }
            }
```

and interface:

```
public interface Find<E, D> {
    E findId(D id);
}
```

and class:

```
class Name implements Find<MyType,String>{
...
}
```

When my code snipet is executed I expect to have only one method with returned type MyType but I have 2?

*class com.example.MyType with method findId*

and

**class java.lang.Object** with method **findId**

From where this findBy can come from? From the interface or from Spring? (I do not have define method findID with returnedType Object (I am sure).

And Doc of getDeclaredMethods()

> Returns an array of {@code Method} objects reflecting all the
>        * methods declared by the class or interface represented by this
>        * {@code Class} object. This includes public, protected, default
>        * (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.
>        * The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any
>        * particular order.  This method returns an array of length 0 if the class
>        * or interface declares no methods, or if this {@code Class} object
>        * represents a primitive type, an array class, or void.  The class
>        * initialization method {@code } is not included in the
>        * returned array. If the class declares multiple public member methods
>        * with the same parameter types, they are all included in the returned
>        * array.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of `E` generic type, and type erasure. Generic type is replaced with `Object` in byte code.

If you take a look at [this example](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Why%20does%20the%20compiler%20add%20casts%20when%20it%20translates%20generics?), you'll see that

```
private X first; 
private Y second; 
public X getFirst() { return first; } 
public Y getSecond() { return second; }
```

turns to this after type erasure

```
private Object first; 
private Object second; 
public Object getFirst() { return first; } 
public Object getSecond() { return second; }
```

The reason you see an additional method next to yours is because compiler adds a synthetic [bridge method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods).

Quote related to the above example:

> The NumericValue class implements the non-generic Comparable interface after type erasure, and the compiler adds a so-called bridge method . The bridge method is needed so that class NumericValue remains a class that implements the Comparable interface after type erasure.

**See also:**

- [What is the concept of erasure in generics in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)

Comment: Ok but why such with class com.example.MyType is returned not only with Object?

Comment: predrag-maric is on the right track here.  Type erasure is what's going on.  Specifically, the Java compiler is generating [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Comment: @Xelian I've updated my answer. As Keegan already said, bridge methods are the answer.

Comment: So is there solution to change getDeclaredMethods with other method from Reflection API to get all methods?

Comment: @Xelian You can call `isBridge()` on the method to check if it is a bridge method.

Comment: If isBridge() returns true-> this method's return type is Object. Thanks that works.