# Can I turn a type parameter into a Class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a server that can return a few different kinds of objects, and I'm using GSON's fromJson to try and deal with it. So I want to write a method that sends a GET to the server and parses the result as an object of the right type. Basically I want to be able to do

```
Foo foo = getStuff("foo_url");
```

or

```
Bar[] bars = getStuff("bar_url");
```

and have it just work. So here's what I got so far (the "get" function is defined elsewhere and sends an HTTP GET request to the given URL and returns the response):

```
<T> T getStuff(String url) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = get(url);
    String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    response.close();
    return gson.fromJson(body, /* ???? */);
}
```

So I need to replace the /* ???? */ with a Class object that represents T so that getStuff will give me back a T. It didn't work to just put `T` in there, nor did `new Class<T>().class`, so I'm out of hacks.

Can I do this?

Comment: `getStuff("foo_url", Foo.class)`, `getStuff("bar_url", Bar[].class)`

Comment: Yeah but that's ugly and I want to do it with one parameter to getStuff.

Comment: That's not possible. You need an extra hint, and you can't get that with generic type arguments.

Comment: That's pretty lame. Hopefully we'll both learn something today.

Comment: Sotirios is right, you need the extra argument. The actual value of the generic type parameter is not known at runtime, it only exists at compile time.

Comment: Maybe it would help to take a look at how it's done in https://github.com/balanced/balanced-java, specifically around https://github.com/balanced/balanced-java/blob/777c94c5cabe32427f977e94dfa0d67604c38e73/src/main/java/com/balancedpayments/core/Client.java#L197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. By the time the method is executed, the type parameter has been [erased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java). No information about type parameters is stored at runtime or baked into the bytecode at compile time; for example, the compiler does not secretly add an extra argument to your method and pass in `Foo.class` at the call site. You have to pass the Class yourself.