# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com..dto.PersonDto

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Here I am trying to call service personModule for data ,
but when i call below code then it's thowing error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.dto.PersonDto"
```

My Code:

```
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(personModuleUrl);
url.append("/person/getPersonData?personId=");url.append(personId);              
Set<PersonDto> per= ResponseEntity.getForEntity(url.toString(), Set.class).getBody();
```

Comment: Can you show use what is `ResponseEntity` here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you only give `Set` as parameter for getEntity. Looks like this creates a `Set<LinkedHashMap>`, which cannot be converted to `Set<PersonDto>`.

For more information on how to do it properly, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369226/10491383