# Using Jackson with generic types

Tags: java, json, jackson, mixins

Let's assume I have the following class:

```
public class Sample<T> {
    private String smth;
}
```

I need to have the name of the "smth" property depends on the generic type. For example: `Sample<String>` should be turned to `{"string":value}` and `Sample<Integer>` to `{"int":value}`

I tried to use Jackson MixIn but it can be applied only on the concrete class (not generic)

Can anyone propose somethig to sort it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called **erasure**.

If you have this code

```
Sample<String> mysample = ...
```

and want to transform *mysample* in `{"string":value}`

It is not possible.

At runtime, the *< String>* information is not available. This is called erasure.

[What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)

[Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)