# Generic method accepts different data type list

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a method that **accepts all data type list**. But it accepting only same data type list. I have done below

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> List<E> mergeArray(List<E> ...list) {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>(); 
        for(List<E> temp : list) {
            result.addAll(temp); 
        }
        return result; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args1) {
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"); 
        List<Double> l2 = Arrays.asList(2.3, 2.2, 4.5); 
        List<Integer> l3 = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3); 
        List<String> l4 = Arrays.asList("Hello1", "World1"); 
        System.out.println(mergeArray(l1, l2));
    }
```

Here the method `mergeArray` accepts only `mergeArray(l1, l4)` //Same data type.
If I passed different data type mean `mergeArray(l1,l2) or mergeArray(l1,l2,l3)`  it doesn't work.
Is it possible to do?

Comment: Do you have an actual use for a list whose elements don't have anything in common?

Comment: you should use `@SafeVarargs`

Comment: @newacct Thank you I modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly *possible*, but I'm not sure it's *useful*.  Here's a way to do it with bounded wildcard type parameters, though, that doesn't necessarily require the return type to be `List<Object>`:

```
public static <E> List<E> mergeArray(@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<? extends E> ...list) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>(); 
    for(List<? extends E> temp : list) {
        result.addAll(temp); 
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: would you please little bit explain List<? extends E> regards this question?

Comment: `List<? extends E>` means a `List` whose type parameter can be `E` or any type that extends `E`.  If you rely on Java to infer `E`, then it will choose the nearest mutual superclass of the type parameters of all the argument arrays (where the type parameters themselves are eligible choices).  For the arguments in your test method that will be `Object`, but if the arguments had types `List<Integer>` and `List<Double>` then it would be `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java doesn't mean you can put any object in, that would be `List<Object>`. It's that it works on all object types but they all need to be of the same object type when used. This is through a process called Erasure. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java).

Comment: Erasure is not connected to the fact that generics enforce the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well skip generics altogether if you want to store any kind of object in a single list. That's exact opposite of why generics were actually developed i.e. to make collections type safe