# Generics in reflection

Tags: java

I'm creating a Class object for class Box which has a type parameter. And in the place where I get Class objects it throws an warning that class type is raw -                (Class objCB = b.getClass()).

My doubt is while creating a Class object for any class with type parameter why should generics come into the picture. And how to resolve the warning. Below is my code

```
//Box Class
public class Box <T extends Comparable<T>>{

public T objA;
public T objB;      

public void set(T t1, T t2)
{
    this.objA = t1;
    this.objB = t2;
}

public int compare()
{       
return this.objA.compareTo(this.objB);      
}   

}

// Refelection class
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Test6 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

//using getClass
Box <Integer> b = new Box <Integer>();
Class objCB = b.getClass();    //warning thrown here
Method[] methods = objCB.getMethods();  
for (Method m : methods)
{
    System.out.println(m.getName());
}

System.out.println("==================");

//using class
Class objC2 = Box.class;   //warning thrown here
Field[] fields = objC2.getFields();
for (Field f : fields)
{   
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}

System.out.println("==================");
//using forName()   
Class objC3 = Class.forName("Box");  //warning thrown here
Type[] types = objC3.getTypeParameters();
for (Type t : types)
{
    System.out.println(t.toString());
}

System.out.println("==================");
//using Type()  
Class objI = Integer.TYPE;  //warning thrown here
System.out.println(objI.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: Class `Class` has itself a type parameter. You get a warning because you are using `Class` without a type parameter. [Don't use raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Use `Class<Box<Integer>>` or at least `Class<?>` instead of the raw type `Class`.

Comment: <?> works but using <Box<Integer>> throws a compile error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Box> to Class<Box<Integer>>

Comment: To understand some of the problem here you need to know [what type erasure is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The `Class` class has a generic parameter which in general should point to the type the class represents. It's used to safely instantiate the object using `newInstance()` or `getConstructor(...).newInstance()` or call some other methods like `cast()` or `getEnumConstants()`. For example, you can use without a type cast:

```
Integer i = Integer.class.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(0);
```

In many cases it's difficult to preserve exact type argument. For example, `Object.getClass()` method has return type `Class<?>`. On the other hand, when you are not going to instantiate the class, having `Class<?>` is fine. So replace your raw `Class` with `Class<?>`.

If you later want to change it to some specific class in safe manner, you may use `asSubclass`:

```
Class<?> someClass = i.getClass();
// type check is done here: CCE will be thrown if someClass is not Integer.class
Class<? extends Integer> c = someClass.asSubclass(Integer.class);
// No type check is necessary here.
Integer ii = c.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(0);
```

In any case using raw types is bad and may lead to serious problems, that's why the warning is issued. Avoid raw types.