# Java reflection get runtime type when using generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am wondering how can I get the runtime type which is written by the programmer when using generics. For example if I have `class Main<T extends List<String>>` and the programmer write something like

```
Main<ArrayList<String>> main = new Main<>();
```

how can I understand using reflection which class extending `List<String>` is used?

I'm just curious how can I achieve that. With

```
main.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getBounds[]
```

I only can understand the bounding class (not the runtime class).

Comment: You can't. In Java specific generic types are [erased at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). They are compilers tool, not runtime.

Comment: As mentioned by Pshemo, this is not supported by the JVM due to type erasure. More about some work-arounds in [Get generic type of class at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

Comment: Are you looking to get the type arguments for any arbitrary generic type? Or for a particular type that you can change?

Comment: Thank you all, for your attention. I know that the generics are removed after compilation, but I am wondering how then ClassCastException is thrown runtime  ?  Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but how it knows to throws this exception if there isn't any information about classes. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments above point out, due to [**type erasure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java) you can't do this. But in the comments, the follow up question was:

> I know that the generics are removed after compilation, but I am wondering how then ClassCastException is thrown runtime ? Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but how it knows to throws this exception if there isn't any information about classes.

The answer is that, although the type parameter is erased from the **type**, it still remains in the **bytecode**.

Essentially, the compiler transforms this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
String value = list.get(0);
```

into this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("foo");
String value = (String) list.get(0); // note the cast!
```

This means that the type `String` is no longer associated with the type `ArrayList` in the bytecode, but it still appears (in the form of a class cast instruction). If at runtime the type is different you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

This also explains why you can get away with things like this:

```
// The next line should raise a warning about raw types
// if compiled with Java 1.5 or newer
List rawList = new ArrayList();

// Since this is a raw List, it can hold any object.
// Let's stick a number in there.
rawList.add(new Integer(42));

// This is an unchecked conversion. Not always wrong, but always risky.
List<String> stringList = rawList;

// You'd think this would be an error. But it isn't!
Object value = stringList.get(0);
```

And indeed if you try it, you'll find that you can safely pull the `42` value back out as an `Object` and not have any errors at all. The reason for this is that the compiler doesn't insert the cast to `String` here -- it just inserts a cast to `Object` (since the left-hand side type is just `Object`) and the cast from `Integer` to `Object` succeeds, as it should.

Anyhow, this is just a bit of a long-winded way of explaining that type erasure doesn't erase **all** references to the given type, only the type parameter itself.

And in fact, as a now-deleted answer here mentioned, you can exploit this "vestigial" type information, through a technique called [Gafter's Gadget](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html), which you can access using the `getActualTypeArguments()` method on `ParameterizedType`.

The way the gadget works is by creating an empty subclass of a parameterized type, e.g. `new TypeToken<String>() {}`. Since the anonymous class here is a subclass of a concrete type (there is no type parameter `T` here, it's been replaced by a real type, `String`) methods on the type have to be able to return the real type (in this case `String`). And using reflection you can discover that type: in this case, `getActualTypeParameters()[0]` would return `String.class`.

Gafter's Gadget can be extended to arbitrarily complex parameterized types, and is actually often used by frameworks that do a lot of work with reflection and generics. For example, the Google Guice dependency injection framework has a type called [`TypeLiteral`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) that serves exactly this purpose.

Comment: Stellar answer, I'd never thought about the `Object value = stringList.get(0);` trick before.