# Java generics and reflection(jenkov blog)

Tags: java, generics, reflection

While going through some Jakov Jenkov blogs on java reflection and generics , I found the following paragraph:

> When runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like `java.util.List`, there is no way of knowing what type is has been parameterized to. This makes sense since the type can be parameterized to all kinds of types in the same application. But, when you inspect the method or field that declares the use of a parameterized type, you can see at runtime what type the paramerizable type was parameterized to.

Can anyone please elaborate on the paragraph?

I got confused by the statement "when runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following small program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyClass {
    ArrayList<String> stringList;

    public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
        return stringList;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(intList.getClass().toGenericString());  
        System.out.println(MyClass.class.getMethod("getStringList").toGenericString());
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
public class java.util.ArrayList<E>
public java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> MyClass.getStringList()
```

As you see, the fact that `intList` is an `ArrayList<Integer>` is not known at run-time, but the fact that `MyClass.getStringList()` returns an `ArrayList<String>` is.

The reason is, that all `ArrayList` instances (some of which may be `ArrayList<Integer>`s and others `ArrayList<String>`s) share the same `Class` object:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(stringList.getClass() == intList.getClass());
```

would output `true`. So `intList.getClass()` cannot know anything about the type parameters of the object.

On the other hand, the object returned by `MyClass.getStringList()` is always a string list, and this information can be seen at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you have the following class:

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Inspecting the parameterized type itself means inspecting `list1.getClass()` or `list2.getClass()`. They are absolutely indistinguishable:

```
System.out.println(list1.getClass() == list2.getClass());
// prints true
```

All instances of `ArrayList` are instances of the same class regardless of parameterization, so having just `list1.getClass()` or `list2.getClass()` you have no way to determine whether it was parameterized with `Integer` or `String`.

However if you have direct access to the field, you can do it:

```
System.out.println(ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredField("list1").getGenericType());
// prints java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
System.out.println(ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredField("list2").getGenericType());
// prints java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

Because here you're accessing the field itself and actual parameterization is stored in the class file together with the field declaration. The same is possible if you inspect the method parameter or return value: it's actual generic signature is also stored in the class file along with erased signature.

Answer (score 0):

The generics in java is a compile time thing. There are no ways to get any information of generics types in runtime, but the non-null *objects* contain information about their types.

So, if you have a method, that takes the `List<T>` and the list is not empty, you can make something like that:

`if (list.get(0) instanceOf X) {
    // ...
}`

If you read some java code with generics, you'll found many methods like that:

```
<T> T getSomething(Class<T> aClass);
```

The reason, why some object, carrying the type is required, is that there is no such thing as generic types in runtime at all.

Comment: Some generic information is available where the compiler would need it to check you code, e.g. field, method parameters, method return type, super classes and interfaces.  It is not available via the object unless it is indirectly via one of the means mentioned.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are maybe right, but it's often hard to understand the applicability borders of that things anyway.
Did you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3403976/1240328

Comment: Yes, information in code is available via reflection.  However, there is no additional information in an instance.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words it just states that the list doesn't know what type of data it holds and doesn't care. Your program will find out what type it is at runtime when you invoke a method to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to those articles: [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java) and [one more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

They explain the "erasure mechanism".