# Create Collection (e.g. Map) with specified Types - not using generic Object class

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a Map with specified types and not generic Object class objects?

Lets say i have a Type object that is `javafx.collections.ObservableMap<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>`

and i get the subtypes of the map like this:

```
Class<?> keyClass = Class.forName(objectGenericTypes[0].getTypeName());
Class<?> valueClass = Class.forName(objectGenericTypes[1].getTypeName());
```

Can i create a Map object with the specified `Integer`and `String`classes from those `keyClass` and `valueClass` objects without using `Map<Object,Object>`? (`Integer`and `String` can be any other Class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type parameters in Java are not reified, due to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584). (There is an exception to this: if you create a concrete subclass of a generic type, then the type parameters for the parent class are "hard coded" into the subclass and can be found using reflection. This technique is called [Gafter's Gadget](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).)

In the common case where you create a type like `new HashMap<String, Integer>` there is nothing in the type at runtime that indicates the type parameters. Instead the type parameters are inserted as casts at the point where you *use* the corresponding values.

If you want to create a new map with the same type parameters, you'll need to capture them in the generic signature:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> newMapWithParametersOf(Map<K, V> map) {
  return new HashMap<>();
}
```

Underneath the hood, the object returned here actually still *is* a `HashMap<Object, Object>` (or more accurately, a raw `HashMap` without any type parameters at all). Since the generic types are only used by the compiler this is safe: the compiled bytecode will have the necessary casts inserted at the places where the type is used instead.

Comment: Thanks. That answers a few questions and actually means i can't use it for my problem :(