# Foo.class works but List<Foo>.class doesn't

Tags: java

I need to supply class. I have a class Foo so if I supply `Foo.class` it works fine but I need to supply `List<Foo>.class` but this doesn't exist.

How can I pass class of List Type?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, `List<Foo>.class` does not exist, due to type erasure.  There is only `List.class`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, due to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java). At runtime, generic type parameters are erased, and no longer available. As a result, although `List<Foo>` may exist at compile-time as a generic, at runtime you will only have `List.class`, of type `Class<List>`.

From the [Java Language Specification, version 8, section 15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> It is a compile-time error if the named type is a type variable (§4.4) or a parameterized type (§4.5) or an array whose element type is a type variable or parameterized type.

For example, `List<Foo>.class`, `T.class`, `List<Foo>[].class`, and `T[].class` are all invalid (assuming that `T` is a type parameter).