# unable to get the working of list collection in below scenario

Tags: java

May be this questions is already asked, but i didn't found any words about this,

Problem:   I am not getting the working of below code. Could any one please add some points in order to understand this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


   List list=new ArrayList<>(); 
   list.add("String");
   listOPt(list);
}
public static void listOPt(List<Integer> intList){
        intList.add(343);
        System.out.println(intList.toString());
}
```

output: `[String, 343]`

I am not getting how intList printing string also.

As per my understanding if we add any object before calling `listOPt()` it will insert into `intList` and after that function `intList` accept `Integer` only  is it?

but how it is stored in memory?

Comment: reading about how generics work in java and type erasure might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Comment: What you have shown here is an example of problems of using **raw types**. Search the web for *Java Generics Raw Type* you will get a lot of materials.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

also the oList arraylist is not used in your code example, so for clarity I suggest you remove it.

Comment: does anyone  please add your points on above scenario only. I just need how compiler behave on above scenario?

Comment: The above scenario is not a special scenario. The compiler and jvm behave as they always do with generics (The type information was erased by the compiler and at execution time, a List<A> and a List<B> are the same).

Answer (score 1):

Generics were implemented quite lately in the JDK so it was decided to use [Type Erasure](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/java-generics-type-erasure/).

This means roughly that generics are checked at compile time but the information is lost at runtime. Casting a `List<? extends Object>` to a `List<Integer>` will certainly not remove the `String` item you added. In other cases you could have a compilation error (i.e. if `oList` was a `List<String>`).

Answer (score 0):

At below line,

```
List<? extends Object> oList=new ArrayList<>();
```

java will create a list which can take Object or any subclass of object.

At method `listOPt(List<Integer> intList)`, you intend to use type inference, as you have used <> operator at instantiation. But type inference works at the time of instantiation, where it has created a list which can accept Object and subtype. So in method listOPt(..) it can accept integer.

Basically your List object is as good as `List<Object>`.

Comment: no the `List` object is as good as  `List<Object>` is not correct. It basically of RAW TYPE.  Like in the method `listOPt` it requires a parameter `List<Integer>`. But if you try to pass an object of `List<Object>` It will show an error. But if pass an instance of `List` it will not give any error

Comment: @Amol Binwade...wrong!! oList will accept List of object who extends Object (oList.add("String") will give compile time error) like... List<String> s=new ArrayList<>();    oList=s.

Comment: @Tipu I feel you have the basic understanding of **Type Erasures**. But Could you clarify what you are actually looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler compiles with type erasure. Means when you compile code it will be compiled without your added generic.Please refer [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) and [oracle Java compiler Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

if you still want that your list should accept Integer then please declare it with generics

List list=new ArrayList();

Then you will not be able to add String in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code :

```
List list=new ArrayList<>();
```

You have not used any **Type Erasures** for the declaration of the variable `list`. So the compiler actually converts it to a **RAW TYPE**. Which practically means that now this list variable can be converted to any type of list like you have done `List<Integer>` and the compiler is unable to check the content of the the variable as you have not declared any Type Erasures.

So, immaterial of what has been earlier stored in the variable `list` the compiler simply treats `list` as an instance of `List<Integer>`. Now when you call `intList.toString()` it basically calls the `toString` method of all the objects that are contained in this `list` object and so you get that output.

This is basically the problem you run into while using *Raw Type*. In order that this kind of problem does not happen always use *Type Erasures*.