# ArrayList Modification in Java Versions Why?

Tags: java, arraylist

`ArrayList` declaration is modified from `java` versions one to another.what are the Advantage of the Modified `ArrayList` Declaration.

> eg:  Here I mentioned Three Types of Declaration from Various Version of Java Supported.I Set Java Compilance leve 1.4 in Eclipse

```
 ArrayList val=new ArrayList();//Supported at 1.4  
 ArrayList<String> val=new ArrayList<String>();//Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater 
 ArrayList<String> val=new ArrayList< >();//operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about **L.H.S.** reference variable which is used to hold the object reference.

things are convertible into generic or non-generic resolution during the compile time only.

**Case 1:**

```
ArrayList val=new ArrayList();//Supported at 1.4
```

In this scenario `val` is a non-generic (not strict type) reference which hold a object ref of an `ArrayList`.

you can add any kind of object into this ref variable **(val)**. it is not limited to `String` only. you may also add an `Integer` or `Long` as well.

**Case 2:**

```
ArrayList<String> val=new ArrayList<String>();//Syntax error,
```

> In or After Java 1.5 (generic introduced) this declaration is allowed and ready to use. here `val` is a generic (Strict-type) reference which can hold one and only `String` type Objects you learn more [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-do-we-really-need)

**case 3:**

```
parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater 
 ArrayList<String> val=new ArrayList< >();//operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

> In or After Java 1.7 (diamond operator) this declaration is allowed. its all about Left Hand Side ref. so, val can add only `String` type of object into.

For more clarification [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

Answer (score 5):

It's just a process of continual improvement.

Originally, Java didn't have generics, and so you had to use the first form in your question. The `ArrayList` carried no information about what kind of objects it contained; they were just `Object`. A lot of casting was involved, e.g.:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Thing());
// ...
Thing t = (Thing)list.get(0);
// Blech--^^^^^^^
```

So Java got [*generics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), and we could say what the `ArrayList` would contain<sup>1</sup>:

```
ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<Thing>();
list.add(new Thing());
// ...
Thing t = list.get(0);
//        ^--- No cast! :-)
```

But note the redundancy, I've had to write `ArrayList<Thing>` twice. (Well, really, I should have `List<Thing> list = new ArrayList<Thing>();`, but that's another issue.)

And so Java got the ability to *infer* the type parameter (`<Thing>`) from the variable declaration, which is where `<>` comes from:

```
ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<>();
// No need to repeat ----------------^^
list.add(new Thing());
// ...
Thing t = list.get(0);
//        ^--- No cast! :-)
```

In that example, it doesn't save a lot of typing, but consider a more complicated case, say a map mapping strings to lists of `Thing`:

```
Map<String, List<Thing>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

...is rather shorter / less redundant than

```
Map<String, List<Thing>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Thing>>();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The actual list still just works in terms of `Object`, it's just that the variable carries the type parameter information with it at compile-time (and a little bit at runtime) and the compiler inserts the casts for us; more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313590/157247). This was in order to provide backward-compatibility when generics were added to Java.

Answer (score 0):

As newer versions of Java are rolling out, you see these kind of improvements. For example, let's take your case.

1. Originally Java didn't had [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). They were later supported from version 5 onward. And that's why the first line

   ```
   ArrayList val=new ArrayList(); //Supported at 1.4
   ```

   It only supported type `Object`.
2. As Generics got supported, from version 5, you could now specify the type of parameter on which you wanted to work upon. So this was commonly used in version 1.5 and 1.6.

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<UserDefinedObject> val = new ArrayList<UserDefinedObject>();
   ...
   ```
3. From version 1.7 onward, [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) was introduced.

   > Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method
   >   invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
   >   argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable.
   >   ...
   >   ...
   >   Generic Methods introduced you to type inference, which enables you to invoke a generic method as you would an ordinary method

   and so you could write

   ```
   ArrayList<String> val=new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   In this case, a java compiler can infer the type parameters of a generic method call and you do not have to specify them.

However, since Java is backward compatible, you can use the code from previous version in later version, but not vice versa.