# Java & Kotlin casting with generics. Losing typesafety

Tags: java, generics, casting, kotlin, erasure

When coding in Kotlin/Java, I stumbled onto something rather odd while using casting and generics.
It seems to be possible to have the type system believe a list is of the type `List<Foo>`, while it is actually a `List<Object>`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is possible?

Here is an example in both Kotlin and Java of the issue:

Example in Kotlin

```
fun <T> test(obj: Any): List<T> {
    val ts = ArrayList<T>()
    ts.add(obj as T)
    return ts
}

fun <T> test2(obj: Any): T {
    return obj as T
}

fun <T> test3(obj: Any): List<T> {
    val ts = ArrayList<T>()
    ts.add(test2(obj))
    return ts
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = test<Double>(1) // Returns a list of Integers and doesn't error
    println(x)

    val y = test2<Double>(1) // Casts the Int object to a Double.
    println(y)

    val z = test3<Double>(1) // Returns a list of Integers and doesn't error.
    println(z)
}
```

Example in Java

```
public class Test {
    public static <T> List<T> test(Object obj){
        ArrayList<T> ts = new ArrayList<>();
        ts.add((T) obj);
        return ts;
    }

    public static <T> T test2(Object obj){
        return (T) obj;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> test3(Object obj){
        ArrayList<T> ts = new ArrayList<>();
        ts.add(test2(obj));
        return ts;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> x = test(1); // Returns a list of Integers and doesn't error
        System.out.println(x);

        // Double y = test2(1); // Errors in java an Integers cannot be converted into a Double.
        // System.out.println(y);

        List<Double> z = test3(1); // Returns a list of Integers and doesn't error.
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this works in both OpenJDK and Java SE, so doesn't seem to be an implementation issue in either of those.

Comment: I think  you will get unchecked warning when compiling.

Comment: It compiles fine, but throws a ClassCastException at runtime:

Comment: The generic is only compile time safety because of type erasure.  If you just ignore the warning, than a runtime ClassCastException is understandable.

Comment: Actually the `test()` and `test3()` cases run fine without runtime errors. I think that's the point of OP.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/313584/2891664 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/2891664.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java doesn't have reified generics. That is, generic information does not exist at runtime, and all generic code is "simplified" by a process called erasure. The compiler throws in casts when generic types are known to ensure correctness. You can't cast to a generic type, then, as generic types don't exist enough for the runtime to know whether a value is one or not, and this is why `javac` yells at you for doing this, because it knows you are asking the JVM to do something it cannot possibly do, introducing runtime unsafety.

```
public class Test {
    public static List test(Object obj) { // generic types => erasure = raw types
        ArrayList ts = new ArrayList();
        ts.add(obj); // No cast: List.add has erasure (Ljava.lang.Object;)V
        return ts;
    }

    public static Object test2(Object obj) { // T is unbounded => erasure = Object
        return obj; // No cast: all types <: Object
    }

    public static List test3(Object obj) {
        ArrayList ts = new ArrayList();
        ts.add(test2(obj)); // Note: we don't know what T is, so we can't cast to it and ensure test2 returned one.
        return ts;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List x = test(1); // Returns a list and doesn't error
        System.out.println(x);

        Double y = (Double) test2(1); // Errors in java as an Integer cannot be converted into a Double
        // This is because the compiler needs to insert casts to make generics work
        System.out.println(y);

        List z = test3(1);
        // Unlike y, there isn't a cast in test3 because test3 doesn't know what T is, so the Integer passes through, uncast, into a List<Double>.
        // The JVM can't detect this, because it doesn't even know what a List<Double> is.
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Note how `test2` erases to a glorified identity function, causing `test3` to do exactly the same thing as `test1`, but with a level of indirection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding `reified` in Kotlin to the generic type seems to make it typesafe again. In Java there is no way of doing this typesafe.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler issues a warning when unchecked cast to T is performed.
When there is a such warning in your program type safety is not guaranteed. So the behavior you see is expected.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the second test like that:

```
    Double y = test2(1.0);
    System.out.println(y);
```

In your code `test2(1)`, the argument `1` is autoboxed into an `Integer`, which cannot be cast into a `Double`.