# How to get Class<R> of a Function<T, R>

Tags: java

I have a method with parameter `Function<Entity, Integer>`. I pass a static method reference to that parameter `Entity::getId`.

Is it possible to, during runtime, extract the return class `Class<Integer>` from the function object?

Comment: What is your usecase? Why you need the return class `Class<Integer>` from the function object?

Comment: the return type is generic. i dont know which type it is during runtime without passing a `Class<R>` around

Comment: Show me how you call it. Your client side code which uses this `Class<Integer>`?

Comment: come think of it, i think i can avoid the need for `Class`. but still an interesting question

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the `Class<T>` literal. If you can show me the usage I will be able to help.

Comment: These generic types are primarily intended for compile time. They are not available at runtime because of type erasure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Answer (score 0):

as [GenericDeclaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericDeclaration.html) says:

> getTypeParameters()
>   Returns an array of TypeVariable objects that represent the type variables declared by the generic declaration represented by this GenericDeclaration object, in declaration order.

so supposing you have your class declared as:

```
public class YourParametizedClass<Entity, Integer> {
...
}
```

then you would get the value of the second parameter by doing:

```
YourParametizedClass function=new YourParametizedClass();
function.getClass().getTypeParameters()[1].getName();
```

this will return you "Integer".

Comment: wouldnt it be `Function<Entity, Integer> func = Entity::getId` and then get type parameters of that object?

Comment: well it depends if the class already is defined as YourParametizedClass<Entity, Integer> then it would work