# Why does this method allow a double to be stored in ArrayList of type Integer?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method that is supposed to return an instance of a given collection class with the given entries. The implementation is shown below.

```
public static <E, C extends Collection<E>> C
         initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C> clazz, E... entries) {
    //Collection object
    Collection<E> collection;
    //try to invoke default constructor of C
    try {
        collection = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
             InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    //Add elements to collection
    for (E entry: entries)
        collection.add(entry);
    return (C) collection;
}
```

The problem is that the following code runs even though a `double` should not be able to be stored in a list of type `Integer`

```
 //Create and instantiate an ArrayList with element 1.0
 ArrayList<Integer> list = initalizeAndAddToCollection(ArrayList.class, 1.0);
 System.out.print(list.get(0));
```

Why does this code run, and how do I make it so that it results in either a compile or runtime error?

Edit: I noticed `list.get(0).getClass()` does generate an exception, but I am not sure why either (or why the previous code does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, generics are a compile-time only feature because they're implemented via [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313584/15880).  So while you may think you're creating an `ArrayList<Integer>` at runtime with your `newInstance` call, you're really just creating an `ArrayList`.

In short, reflection breaks type safety for generics in Java.

Comment: On an unrelated side note, this same type of thing would throw an exception in C# because C# generics act more like C++ templates.

Comment: If I am really creating an `ArrayList` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`, shouldn't that cause an exception at runtime when I point a  reference of the type  `ArrayList<Integer>` to an object of the type `ArrayList`?. I noticed `list.get(0).getClass()` does generate a exception, but why not this code?

Comment: `list.get(0).getClass()` should be returning the class for an `Integer` because of something else I didn't mention: When you're dealing with a generic return type, the compiler inserts a cast.  Meaning that `list.get(0)` is actually `((Integer) list.get(0))`

Comment: From what I understand, `list.get(0).getClass()` is actually `((Integer) list.get(0)).getClass()` but `list.get(0)` by itself has no implicit cast (and hence no casting exception). Is there a reason why the latter does not have a implicit cast?

Answer (score 1):

This code gives a warning when I compile it.  The warning says:

```
Note: MyTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

And in fact, when you do what it produces 4 warning messages:

```
MyTest.java:5: warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type E
        initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C> clazz, E... entries) {
                                             ^
  where E,C are type-variables:
    E extends Object declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)
    C extends Collection<E> declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)


MyTest.java:18: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        return (C) collection;
                   ^
  required: C
  found:    Collection<E>
  where E,C are type-variables:
    E extends Object declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)
    C extends Collection<E> declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)
MyTest.java:23: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method initalizeAndAddToCollection in class MyTest is applied to given types
             initalizeAndAddToCollection(ArrayList.class, 1.0);
                                        ^
  required: Class<C>,E[]
  found: Class<ArrayList>,double
  where C,E are type-variables:
    C extends Collection<E> declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)
    E extends Object declared in method <E,C>initalizeAndAddToCollection(Class<C>,E...)
MyTest.java:23: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
             initalizeAndAddToCollection(ArrayList.class, 1.0);
                                        ^
  required: ArrayList<Integer>
  found:    ArrayList
4 warnings
```

These warnings explain why this seemingly incorrect code is compiling.  You are doing things that the compiler *would* tell you are incorrect.

---

> Why does this code run.

Because it is not actually breaking runtime type-safety.

- Type erasure means that the collection is actually storing references to `Object`.
- When you then do `System.out.print(list.get(0));` the parameter type for the `print` call is `Object`. That means no implicit cast to `Integer` is needed.

> and how do I make it so that so that it results in either a compile or runtime error?

If you need a compile time error, tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors.  (Or check for warnings in the compilation output.)

If you need a runtime error, you need to add some explicit runtime type checks probably in your `initalizeAndAddToCollection` method.

Comment: Why does the compiler not implicitly cast `list.get(0)` but seems to implicitly casts `list.get(0).getClass()` (the latter code generates a `ClassCastException`). Wouldn't the same argument apply if I did `System.out.print(list.get(0).getClass())` as this call would return an `Object`?

Comment: Not clear.  But it doesn't matter.  You shouldn't write code like this, and your shouldn't ignore warnings about unchecked conversions ... without examining them carefully.