# Why is it legal to cast an Object array to a generics array?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

When I try to cast an object array to a custom data-type (class) array I get the ClassCastException but when I cast an object array to a generics array, no such error is observed; furthermore, if I pass a custom data-type(class) as a type argument, the ClassCastException is not thrown either.

I experimented several things:

- First, I made a custom data-type called `TestClass`. Then I tried creating an object array and casting it into TestClass
  `TestClass[] b = (TestClass[]) new Object[100];`

  - **Result: ClassCastException**
- I made the Main class (the main() function of  which is conducting the experiments) accepts type arguments (generics) referred to as `Item`. This was followed by a line of code `this.a = (Item[]) new Object[100];` where `a` is an instance variable defined as `Item[] a`.

  - **Result: exit code 0**
- Now, I added a line of code to the `main(String[] args)`: `Main<TestClass> m = new Main<TestClass>();` do note that I passed `TestClass` as a type argument so that in the constructor we face a situation almost identical to that in the first experimental setup, therefore I expect a `ClassCastException`.

  - **Result: exist code 0**

The entire Main class for further reference (assume `TestClass` is defined):

```java
public class Main<Item>{
    Item a[];
    TestClass b[];
    public Main(){
        //this.b = (TestClass[]) new Object[100]; (errors disappear when this line is commented out, otherwise ClassCastException is thrown)
        this.a = (Item[]) new Object[100];
    }
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.b));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a = new Object();
        Main<TestClass> m = new Main<TestClass>(); //TestClass passed as type argument, should cause problems in the constructor
        m.doStuff();
    }
```

Apologies for not using proper Java conventions, I was only experimenting :)

Comment: Pay attention to the compiler warnings you will have got with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java): `Item` is erased to `Object`, so your code becomes

```
public class Main {
    Object a[];

    ...
    this.a = (Object[]) new Object[100];
    ...
}
```

Unsurprisingly that cast succeeds.

Now if you add e.g.

```
TestClass[] b = m.a;
```

to `main`, the compiler will need to insert a cast

```
TestClass[] b = (TestClass[]) m.a;
```

and *that* will fail because `m.a` is really an `Object[]`.