# Is java generic code copied at run-time for each type used OR java uses type casting?

Tags: java, generics

I was reading about how monomorphisation works in Rust, does java work in same way.

Lets say I create below file.

```
public class DummyDTO<T> {
    T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and use `new DummyDTO<Integer>()` & `new DummyDTO<Float>()` will java compiler create two different files for each, Integer and Float or it will Simply replace `T` with Object and will do casting everywhere?

Comment: Also [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313584/6395627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The second one. Literally, replace `T` with `Object` and it will insert casts as necessary.