# How to use Gson to deserialize a json array string to object mode using generic class type?

Tags: json, generics, arraylist, gson

Having a function for deserializing json string into object mode by providing the class type the json string should be deserialized into.
It works for most of the case

```
    fun <T> deserializeJsonStr(jsonString: String, dataClassType: Class<T>):T? {
        var ret: T? = Gson().fromJson<T>(jsonString, dataClassType)
        return ret
    }
```

like

```
// data modle
class TestData1 {
    var userId = 0
    var id = 0
    var title: String? = null
    var body: String? = null
}
// the json string
{
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "the title",
      "body": "the body"
    }

// call the function
val clazz: Class<TestData1> = TestData1::class.java
val theTestData1 = deserializeJsonStr(jsonString, clazz)

it will return the object theTestData1 with the fields filled.
```

But if the json string is for json array:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title1",
    "body": "body1"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title2",
    "body": "body2"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title3",
    "body": "body3"
  }
]
```

Though it should be `ArrayList<TestData1>`, but what is it class type? tried:

```
val clazz: Class<ArrayList<TestData1>> = ArrayList<TestData1>::class.java
val theTestData1 = psreJsonStr(jsonString, clazz)
```

but it does not compile:
[image]
or the `val pojoClass: Class<ArrayList<TestData1>> = ArrayList<>::class.java` does not compile either:
[image]

what would be the data class mode for this json array? or what is the `Class<T>` required by the function param for ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313584): `ArrayList<TestData1>::class.java` is not possible because at runtime the type argument of `ArrayList` is not available, so this would basically be `Class<ArrayList>`<sup>1</sup>. Therefore the compiler does not allow this because it would not be safe.

Gson has its [`TypeToken`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) class to work around this, see also the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Collections-Examples).

In your case you could change your `deserializeJsonStr` to the following:

```kotlin
fun <T> deserializeJsonStr(jsonString: String, dataType: TypeToken<T>): T? {
    // Note: Older Gson versions might require using `dataType.type`
    return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, dataType)
}
```

You would then call the function like this:

```kotlin
val type = object: TypeToken<ArrayList<TestData1>>() {}
val data = deserializeJsonStr(jsonString, type)
```

You could additionally add an overload of `deserializeJsonStr` with [`reified` type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) which makes it make more convenient to use:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> deserializeJsonStr(jsonString: String): T? {
    return deserializeJsonStr(jsonString, object: TypeToken<T>() {})
}
```

```kotlin
// Note: You can even omit the explicit `ArrayList<TestData1>` if the compiler can infer it
val data = deserializeJsonStr<ArrayList<TestData1>>(jsonString, type)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `Class` is a bit special because its direct type argument is not erased at runtime, for example `Class<ArrayList>` is not erased to `Class<Object>`. But for every other generic type the type argument is erased.

Comment: Thanks Marcono! What I tried is just create a derived class form the `TheClass: ArrayLis<TestDat1>`, and it works. I will try with using the `TypeToken<T>`. Can the TypeToken<T> be used for Class<T> interchangeably?

Comment: @lannyf, in the context of Gson yes, I think so. But `TypeToken` is a Gson specific class, so outside of Gson you cannot do much with it. You can also directly create a `TypeToken` for a `Class` with [`TypeToken.get(Class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#get(java.lang.Class)), this avoids having to create anonymous classes through `object: ...`.